# Python code error message that I don't understand

Tags: python, compiler-errors, raspberry-pi

I am having problems decoding this error message for the python on my Raspberry Pi.  Please don't tell me to head to that SE, they sent me here as no one really knew what it means.  It is from [GitHub][1]

Here is the error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pi/piarduino/MissionControl-master/mcDesk.py", line 8, in <module> serialFromArduino = serial.Serial("/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A900aepy-if800-port0", 115200)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in __init__
        self.open()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 276, in open
        raise SerialException("could not open por %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
SerialException: could not open port /dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A900aepy-if800-port0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_FTDI_FT232R_USB_UART_A900aepy-if800-port0'
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Raspberry Pi, but does it not have a readily available tool like `scrot` for taking proper screenshots?

Comment: If your Raspberry Pi's OS is Debian-based, you should be able to type `sudo apt-get install scrot` in terminal to install it, then `scrot` to take a screenshot when it's installed. `scrot -d 5` to take a screenshot after a 5 second delay. There's a [good overview here](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/10/how-to-take-screenshots-on-the-raspberry-pi/).

Comment: Then do you know where it saves the screenshots?

Comment: Unless specified otherwise, `scrot` saves in the current directory. Use the command `pwd` to `p`rint `w`orking `d`irectory if you're unsure of where you currently are. Or you can use `scrot [options] /path/to/your/picture.png` to specify the output location.

Answer (score 1):

Basic troubleshooting:

- Try running your script as root using `sudo`. It's possible you're being denied access to the serial port.
- Run `ls /dev/serial/by-id` in a shell. Make sure the serial port you are trying to open exists and matches exactly with the port you're trying to open in your program.
- If neither of those options work, try [these steps](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/raspberry-pi-serial-port).

If you care to update your question with more details, we may be able to help you further.

Comment: Could it be a problem that I don't have my Arduino hooked up to it yet?  That's the serial part of the code.

Comment: It shouldn't be. Since the serial port can't even open, it also hasn't sent any data, which means it has no way of knowing if anything is listening on the other end or not, for starters.

Comment: This may sound silly, but how do I run code in a shell?

Comment: Open up a terminal window. (There should be a shortcut on the Raspberry Pi desktop - LXTerminal is there by default, I believe.) Then, navigate to the directory your code is in using ls. Then, type `sudo python my_python_code.py`

Comment: I got the same error message as in the screenshot (or now text) above.  Also, I would love to give more information like you asked for above, but I posted everything I know.  The original code, and the output.

Comment: Have you tried running `ls /dev/serial/by-id` to ensure that the file you're looking for exists and is named correctly?

Comment: that didn't change anything